# Finding GPU information (model) in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, operating-system

In Node.js, we can easily use `os` module ([documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_cpus)) in order to obtain CPU information:

```
    os.cpus()[0].model; // → Example: 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 860 @ 2.80GHz'
```

I'm looking for a similar way to obtain **GPU** model and if possible, specifications.

Thanks from ahead for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write a module switching the os.platform(), then execute a command for each os to grab the GPU info, as follows:

```
// Mac OS:
system_profiler | grep GeForce

// Windows:
wmic path win32_VideoController get name

// Linux:
sudo lshw -C display
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why switch all 3?

Comment: in case you run your application on multiple platforms.

Comment: But why should it change the command?
Win x64 and win x32 will use the same command in exec, won't they?

Answer (score 2):

It is currently not possible to get GPU information from Node's *os* object. A possible solution would be executing the command ***system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType***.

In context this would look as following:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
        // Normalise the result here to get the GPU name
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    });
});
```

**Note:** This is specifically for Mac or darwin platform