# Get GPU temperature NODEJS

Tags: node.js, gpu

I'm trying to get gpu temperature using nodeJS.

I found one package on npm called "systeminformation" but I cant get gpu temperature from it.

If there is no package/module for it I would like to know a way how to do it from NodeJS.

Comment: Maybe this could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312583/finding-gpu-information-model-in-node-js

Comment: @zero01alpha I don't believe the package can monitor temperatures or any other live data related to the GPU.

Answer (score 10):

There are not Node.js packages with C/C++ submodules for checking GPU temperature, but you can use CLI for that.

Pros and cons:

- Easy
- You need to know only the CLI command for your OS
- performance can be slow
- maybe you need run your app with `sudo`

For Ubuntu the CLI command looks like:

> nvidia-smi --query-gpu=temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader

Any CLI command execution is async operation so you need callbacks or promises or generators. I prefer async/await approach.

**Example with async/await for 8.9.x Node.js:**

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const execAsync = promisify(exec);
const gpuTempeturyCommand = 'nvidia-smi --query-gpu=temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader'; // change it for your OS

async function getGPUTemperature() {
  try {
    const result = await execAsync(gpuTempeturyCommand);
    return result.stdout;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error during getting GPU temperature');
    return 'unknown';
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I found out that I can do it that way but I'm not sure how to do it on amd GPUS.

Comment: I don't have amd GPUS, so I can't help you with CLI command for that. For me, it looks like other question. In general, are you okey with proposed approach? Does it solve your issue?

Comment: How about compatibility with Windows, etc

Comment: It's depends on Windows version and video card model. Could you try `aticonfig --odgc --odgt` CLI command on your machine?