# How i can get the CPU and GPU temperature using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have OS windows 10. I try to use systeminformation  cpuTemperature and i got -1. Probable the system do not support the api. What i can do? And how i can get GPU temperature?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611904/get-gpu-temperature-nodejs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get GPU temperature NODEJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611904/get-gpu-temperature-nodejs)